# How to export dataset to xml with columns caption

Tags: vb.net

I need to export dataset to xml file. For this i try next sample code:

```
Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()
    dt.TableName ="Test"
    Dim dc As DataColumn = New DataColumn("Name", GetType(String))
    dc.Caption = "ColumnCaption1"
    dt.Columns.Add(dc)

    Dim nr As DataRow = dt.NewRow()
    nr("Name") = "TestRow"
    dt.Rows.Add(nr)

    Dim Xml As System.Xml.XmlDocument = New System.Xml.XmlDocument()
    Dim RootNode As System.Xml.XmlNode = Xml.CreateElement("Export")
    Xml.AppendChild(RootNode)
    Dim DocsNode As System.Xml.XmlNode = Xml.CreateElement("Documents")
    RootNode.AppendChild(DocsNode)

    Dim DocDataSet As DataSet = New DataSet("Doc1")
    DocDataSet.Tables.Add(dt)
    DocDataSet.EnforceConstraints = False

    Dim XmlDoc As System.Xml.XmlDataDocument = New System.Xml.XmlDataDocument(DocDataSet)       
    Dim DocElement As System.Xml.XmlNode = Xml.ImportNode(XmlDoc.DocumentElement, True)
    'DocElement.
    DocsNode.AppendChild(DocElement)

    Dim Settings As System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings = New System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings()
    Settings.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8
    Settings.Indent = True
    Settings.IndentChars = Chr(9)
    Settings.CloseOutput = True
    Settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true

Dim DirectoryName as string = "C:\Temp"
    Dim FileName As String = DirectoryName & "\myExport"
    Dim OutStream As System.IO.FileStream = System.IO.File.Create(FileName)
    Dim Writer As System.Xml.XmlWriter = System.Xml.XmlWriter.Create(OutStream, Settings)
    Xml.WriteTo(Writer)
    Writer.Close()
```

It works and the result of export is:

```
<Export>
    <Documents>
        <Doc1>
            <Test>
                <Name>TestRow</Name>
            </Test>
        </Doc1>
    </Documents>
</Export>
```

But I want that column caption (ColumnCaption1) also will in this xml. How can i do this?

Comment: You could use the `WriteXml` method...?

Comment: You mean DocDataSet.WriteXml ? But in my real case i have more than 1 dataSets and add them to XmlDocument like nodes